# Hibernate Search MultiFieldQueryParser with a Date property

Tags: java, date, lucene, hibernate-search

I upgraded from Hibernate Search 4.4 to 5.3 and sucessfully migrated all issues in [Hibernate Search Migration Guides](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/), but I'm encountering the following error regarding a date property when using `MultiFieldQueryParser`.

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000233: The specified query '+(dateField:value)' contains a string based sub query which targets the numeric encoded field(s) 'myDate'. Check your query or try limiting the targeted entities.
```

My date property is pretty standard

```
@Column(name = "my_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Field
@DateBridge(resolution = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Resolution.DAY)
private Date myDate;
```

Versions

- Hibernate 4.3
- Hibernate Search 5.3
- had to explicitly import (maven) `org.apache.lucene.lucene-queryparser` (4.10.4) for `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MultiFieldQueryParser`, otherwise it wouldn't find it

Also found this issue ([HSEARCH-1870](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1870)) regarding date values, not sure if related.

Am I missing something on `myDate` declaration?

EDIT: missed one migration requirement - see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out I missed one migration requirement: enconding is set to numeric in HS 5 by default.

- [Numeric Field(s) being used by default](http://in.relation.to/2014/12/09/hibernate-search-500-candidate-release-1-spotted-in-the-wild/#H-NumericFieldsBeingUsedByDefault)
- [Numbers and Dates now indexed as Numeric Field by default](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide#jive_content_id_Hibernate_Search_500CR1)

Setting the `encoding` to mimic the behavior in previous versions fixed it.

```
@Column(name = "my_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Field
@DateBridge(resolution = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Resolution.DAY, encoding = EncodingType.STRING)
private Date myDate;
```